# Is there any point to the "travel" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems overly broad to be useful.

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel

Wiki excerpt for [travel](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel):

> Questions related to any kinds of travel where entering space is involved.

Comment: Another point to consider is how [tag:travel] and [tag:tourism] relate to each other and if we need both.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to say either way just yet, but I'll explore things to consider.

Most of the questions that have the tag at the moment *should not have it*. So if we keep the tag and assume it's for "travel" in the tourism sense or in the sense of [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) but don't think that the [tourism](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tourism) tag is sufficient, then we'd have to remove it from say three dozen questions.

These **might** be candidates for an actual "travel" tag:

- [Why would it take so long (22 minutes!) to travel from Hong Kong to Singapore flying SpaceX?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49189/12102)
- [Could the Space X "Starship" be modified for point to point travel on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46135/12102)
- [g-forces of suborbital versus orbital passenger travel](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23184/12102)
- [Near-future consumer space travel](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/789/12102)
- [What would happen to communication if we stayed in contact with a person going to mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21974/12102)
- [Will SpaceX open up space to the public?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4676/12102)
- [What are/were the Customs requirements for astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37656/12102)
- [g-forces of suborbital versus orbital passenger travel](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23184/12102)
- [Would a point-to-point suborbital spaceflight have a "negative" perigee?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3531/12102)
- [Are there any proposals for a permanent orbital interplanetary ferry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7811/12102)
- [How serious is a contagion in space flight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7985/12102)
- [How will SpaceX's Starship accommodate its 100 passengers from the effects of micro-gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37651/12102)
- [Will SpaceX's moon mission carry any engineers to fix the craft or will the artists be trained for these operations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30764/12102)

and there's [Axiom’s private habitat (which) will detach itself and become the world’s first commercial free-flying space station](https://www.wired.com/story/what-comes-after-the-international-space-station/)

and there's that video: